# ASP.NET MVC - Nested Editor Templates Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

I have two editor templates:

UploadFiles.cshtml:

```
@model HttpPostedFileBase[]
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model, "UploadFile", new { multiple = true })
```

UploadFile.cshtml:

```
@model HttpPostedFileBase
@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { type = "file", multiple = Convert.ToBoolean(ViewBag.Multiple) ? "multiple" : "" })
<!-- Additional code here i don't wish to repeat in both controls -->
```

Notice how UploadFiles.cshtml template accepts an array and then calls the UploadFile.cshtml template and passes in multiple = true via the view data.

The problem i have is if i say:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Files, "UploadFiles")
```

It doesn't render anything.

However if i say:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.File, "UploadFile")
```

It renders correctly.

I'd appreciate if someone could show me how this can be achieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UploadFiles.cshtml, you're passing `Model`, which is an array, to UploadFile.cshtml, which does not take an array. Did you mean to wrap that line in a foreach?

```
foreach (var file in Model)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => file, "UploadFile", new { multiple = true })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe i didn't notice i was passing in the wrong model type. However the array for the files is null and will not render anything. After further research it appears what i'm trying to do won't work as it will always become a partial template of the editor. I will accept your answer as it did point me in the right direction.